# Implement permalink in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net application every category is having multiple dealer locations so clicking on a particular dealer it should navigate to that particular dealer section of that page and so that I can send that link to my anyone then they can observe that particular portion of the web page for this I want to know how to  implement this in my asp.net web application

Comment: A little more information might be useful...  In what context, using what framework.  Why is it changing?

Answer (score 0):

have a look on:

http://csharp-codesamples.com/2009/03/aspnet-permalinks-using-url-rewriting/